# Is there a major difference between either CPU, RAM or Storage capacity needs for the leader or contributor nodes in a production K8S cluster?

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, resource-management, kubeadm

I have already allocated 3 VPS for an initial multiple timezone cluster.

- 12 single-core vCPUs
- ≈50 GB RAM
- ≈1TB SSD storage
- 1 EST,1 CST,& 1 PST

Before I jump in however, I would like to know if there are there any major differences in resource usage between leader and contributor nodes?

ie:

- Do leader nodes hold containers/replicas or simply orchestrate the contributor nodes (thus saving storage in ratio to contributors running containers and holding images, at least in theory).
- Are there other workload splits between leader/contributors that
  would likewise cause a uneven ratio in either RAM or vCPU usage
  between nodes based on their leader/contributor roles respectively?

If I can provision a leader server that uses fewer resources than either its contributor node counterpart by ratio, especially in the storage department, then I may add another server as leader before initial deploy for three way, cross zone contributor load balancing, etc.

Comment: No. And I thank you. I understand "depends" is always the answer when asking for spec provisioning especially...

I want no personal use case info, just if Kubernetes eats resources between L/C nodes differently to a WIDE ratio in K8S due to role. I can use the calculator from there ( won't even need it) Thanks. Adding personal specs at the beginning would give that impression. My fault.

Comment: If you have three notes, that makes you 3 control planes? Resources usage would be comparable. If you go with 1 control plane: it's up to you, to schedule your workloads in a coherent manner. You could set it up to unevenly distribute containers. If you aim to shut down servers and lighten your bill. Or do the contrary. It depends: Kubernetes would deal with your hardware, following your instructions.

Comment: Side note: spreading a cluster in several timezone (thus, I assume, distinct locations, with variable link quality), definitely isn't a recommended scenario. Maybe consider setting up 3 clusters.